# issue with positioning text inside a ribbon

Tags: html, css

Here is a simple ribbon I want to position at the left upper corner of the screen:

```css
.ribbon {
  width: 200px;
  background: #e43;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #ffffff;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  font-family: "Open Sans Regular";
  font-size: 1.5em;
  top: -10px;
  left: -80px;
  height: 80px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.ribbon.new {
  background: #9ddc03;
}
```

```html
<div class="ribbon new">NEW</div>
```

As you see the `New` word on the green ribbon is not totally visible because it is on the upper edge of the rectangle.

How can I position the ribbon's text on the lower edge of the rectangle so that we can see it correctly.

I used the below flex postioning on the ribbon class but it pushes the text to the right and not the center:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
align-items: flex-end;
```

Comment: a bigger line-height (80px) will fix it

Comment: You can also try the flex approach you already started. Some [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oh0Lgtyr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can update your code like below:

```css
.ribbon {
  background: #e43;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin:top;
  padding:40px 100px 0; /* adjust the 40px to control the height (the 100px need to be a big value) */
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.ribbon.new {
  background: #9ddc03;
}
```

```html
<div class="ribbon new">NEW</div>
```